# PLay 2.6: Equivalent API of Configuration.path in Config

Tags: playframework

I am using play 2.6 now, migrated from Play 2.4.
In play 2.4 I was using Configuration.path().getAbsolutePath(); 
As per play 2.6 documentation the Configuration is replaced as com.typesafe.config.Config;
But i am not seeting any equivalent path() api here.

Any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to inject Environment class.

```
private final Environment environment;

@Inject
public YourConstructor(Environment environment)
    this.environment = environment;
}
```

Now to get the root path:

```
environment.rootPath();
```